# Displaying AlertDialog when a button in listview is clicked

Tags: android

How to display an AlertDialog when a button in listview is clicked.
NOTE : The Listview is created using Custom Adapter.

The listview consists of 3 TextViews and a Button.
So I need to know how to display an alertdialog when I click the button present in the listview content.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Within your `Adapter.getView` method, just set a `View.OnClickListener` to the `Button` with an anonymous inner type. For example:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
                builder.setMessage("This is just an example!");
                builder.create().show();
            }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, I think whatever code block you have provided will work for the button available in an activity. But here I need to show an alert dialog on click of button inside a Custom List View. I am having trouble with Context used by AlertDialog.Builder().The getContext() as in your code doesn't work inside CustomAdapter.

Comment: Then pass the `Context` in as a parameter to the constructor of the adapter and hold a reference to it.